# Ruby SSL Client

Tags: ruby, ssl

I've got a SSL Echo Server working fine when I tested with

```
gnutls-cli --starttls --port 9002 --insecure localhost
```

My SSL Echo server is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'socket';
require 'openssl';
certfile = 'privkey.pem';
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9002;

server = TCPServer.new( host, port );

# Establish an SSL context 
sslContext = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
sslContext.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open( "myssl.cert.cert" ))
sslContext.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open( "myssl.cert.key" ))

# Create SSL server
sslServer = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new( server, sslContext );

# Don't expect an immidate SSL handshake upon connection.
sslServer.start_immediately = false;

sslSocket = sslServer.accept;
sslSocket.puts( "Toast.." );
# Server loop
while line = sslSocket.gets
  line.chomp!;
  if "STARTTLS" == line
    # Starting TLS
    sslSocket.accept;
  end
  sslSocket.puts( "Got '#{line}'" );
end
sslSocket.close;
```

My Client is however, not working (which I borrow somewhere in StackOverflow) as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "socket"
require "thread"
require "openssl"

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9002

socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
expectedCert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("myssl.cert.cert"))
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket)
ssl.sync_close = true
ssl.connect
if ssl.peer_cert.to_s != expectedCert.to_s
  stderrr.puts "Unexpected certificate"
  exit(1)
end

Thread.new {
  begin
    while lineIn = ssl.gets
      lineIn = lineIn.chomp
      $stdout.puts lineIn
    end
  rescue
    $stderr.puts "Error in input loop: " + $!
  end
}

while (lineOut = $stdin.gets)
  lineOut = lineOut.chomp
  ssl.puts lineOut
end
```

Error I've got.

```
./sslclient.rb:13:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from ./sslclient.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Why is there a error in ssl.connect? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side you start with plain text, send a welcome message and expect a starttls command - only then you upgrade to TLS. But on the client side you immediatly try to upgrade to TLS after the TCP connect, e.g. without reading the server hello and without sending the starttls command.